# Need help understanding a chunk of code

Tags: code

```
mask[vxy_, steps_] := 
  Module[{r, c, vv}, 
    (
    {r, c} = RandomInteger[{1, steps - 3}, 2];
    vv = Partition[Partition[vxy, 2], steps];
    vv[[r ;; r + 3, c ;; c + 3]] = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 4, 2}];
    sel = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {steps, steps}];
    vv = Flatten[vv*sel + (1 - sel)*RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {steps, steps, 2}]];
    vv(*+RandomReal[{-0.2,0.2},Length[vv]]*)
    )];
```

This is the chunk of code I don't understand. Specifically in these parts:

```
 vv = Partition[Partition[vxy, 2], steps];
 vv[[r ;; r + 3, c ;; c + 3]] = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 4, 2}];
```

I understand how `vv` is created, but I don't understand the manipulation that happens next.

Please! Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Part of the culture of Mathematica seems to be to try to turn words into punctuation characters.  Fortunately you can look up those punctuation characters like `;;` in the help system. If you look at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html it shows examples of what `;;` does. The examples there hint that `vv[[r;;r+3,c;;c+3]]=...` is going to assign to a 4 by 4 block inside the vv matrix. It seems that is going to do in one step what `v[[r,c]]=` and then `v[[r+1,c}=` etc etc until it finally does all 16 of those assignments. Read `RandomReal` doc to understand the right hand side.